# Cassandra 3.x with Datastax Enterprise

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Datastax so please forgive the newb question.

I would like to use Cassandra 3.x with Datastax Enterprise. Is this possible? Can you upgrade Cassandra that comes with Datastax Enterprise?

Thanks
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to upgrade Cassandra inside of DataStax Enterprise.  Realistically I wouldn't expect a version of DSE with a 3.x Cassandra core at least until summer (2016).  And if you'd like to run Cassandra 3.x in production, you should join the [user mailing list](http://www.planetcassandra.org/apache-cassandra-mailing-lists/) and pay attention to the bugs that come across.

Comment: thank you. Do you think Cassandra 3.x is production ready? We are about 3 months away from a production install. The major feature we need is materialized views.

Comment: I'm not Aaron, but 3 months may be long enough for it to stabilize somewhat. If you've written code assuming MVs, you'll have to stick with 3.x. Definitely keep an eye on the Apache Cassandra JIRA for open bugs that may impact you.